# How to get the substring from a value in Mule 4

Tags: mule

My string value is "abc.xyz.lmn.22"
I need to get the last 2 digits i.e 22 from this string .

Or I can explain my scenario where I have string of 26 characters and I want last two characters i.e 25th and 26th.
How can I get that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a DataWeave expression. With the [range selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-selectors) you can select a substring. Using negative indexes for the selector you can start from the end of the string:

```
#[payload[-2 to -1]]
```

Depending on your payload you might need to specify an output type.